# Dynamically type array in Matlab to Fortran

Tags: arrays, dynamic, types, casting, fortran

Matlab has a capability to have a dynamically typed array.  For example, the matlab code is

```
function testing1
clc;
close all;
    chrom_len = 35;


function out = newChromosome(len)
genes_pool = struct(...
    'gene',       {'#', 'U-', 'Rs', '+', '-', '*', '/', '^'}, ...
    'stackDepth', {0,   0,    1,    2,   2,   2,  2,  2},...
    'deltaStack', {1,   1,    0,   -1,  -1,   -1, -1, -1});

function gene = newGene(stackDepth)
    % Select an appropriate gene
    done = false;    
    while ~done
        ind = randi([1 numel(genes_pool)], 1, 1);

        if genes_pool(ind).stackDepth <= stackDepth
            done = true;
        end
    end
    % Generate output

    gene = genes_pool(ind);
        disp('start');
        disp('gene.gene is ');
        disp(gene.gene);
         disp('stop');
    if gene.gene == '#'
        gene.gene = round(randn(1,1) * 5);
        disp('new gene.gene is ');
        disp(gene.gene);
        disp('the gene is ');
        disp(gene);
    end
   end

 genes = {}; stack = [];
 stackDepth = 0;    
 i = 1;
 while i <= len || (i > len && stackDepth ~= 1)
     gene = newGene(stackDepth);
 %    disp('outside gene');
 %    disp(gene);
    class(gene.gene) 
    stackDepth = stackDepth + gene.deltaStack;
 %    disp('stackDepth');
 %    disp(stackDepth);
    genes = [genes, gene.gene];
 %   disp('genes');
 %    disp(genes);
    stack = [stack, stackDepth];
 %    disp('stack')
 %   disp(stack);
    i = i + 1;
    if strcmp(gene.gene, 'X') && rand(1,1) < 0.5
        genes = [genes, randi([2 4], 1)]; stackDepth = stackDepth + 1;
        stack = [stack, stackDepth];
        genes = [genes, '^']; stackDepth = stackDepth - 1;
        stack = [stack, stackDepth];
    end
    return;
 end
 out = struct('genes', {genes}, 'stack', {stack});
 return; 
end

newChromosome(2) 
end
```

The first run Matlab output (I use GNU Octave which is the same thing) is,

```
start
gene.gene is
U-
stop
ans = char
```

The second run Matlab output is,

```
start
gene.gene is
#
stop
new gene.gene is
-11
the gene is

scalar structure containing the fields:

gene = -11
stackDepth = 0
deltaStack =  1
ans = double
```

When I translate Matlab to Fortran I want to duplicate output so that output Fortran is the same type as in Matlab.  The gene.gene results can be either character or double.  This means, it can have two types.
Is it possible to do the same in Fortran?  How do I dynamically type the variable in Fortran?  I believe it has something to do with type casting.
So far, my Fortran solution is,

```
function newchromosome(clen) result(out1)
implicit none

 type garray
 character*2 :: gene; 
 integer     :: stackdepth; 
 integer     :: deltastack;
 end type 

 type(garray), dimension(8) :: genespool
 type(garray), dimension(1) :: gene2

  integer,intent(in) :: clen;
  integer :: out1;
  integer :: inttest;

  genespool = [garray('#',0,1),garray('X',0,1),garray('U-',1,0), &
         garray('+',2,-1),garray('-',2,-1),garray('*',2,-1), &
         garray('/',2,-1),garray('^',2,-1) ]

  gene2 = [garray('s',0,0) ]  

  out1 = clen;
  inttest = newgene(2); 

  contains

  function newgene(stackdepth) result(out2)
  integer, intent(in) :: stackdepth;
  integer :: out2;
  logical :: done;  
  integer :: ind;
  real    :: rnd1;
  character*2, dimension(:), allocatable:: answer2;
  character*2 :: answer;

 answer = 'ye'
 out2=0;
 allocate(answer2(1)); 
!  gene=0;
!  gene = stackdepth;

  done = .FALSE.

  do while (done .EQV. .FALSE.)
    call random_number(rnd1);
    ind = nint(rnd1*size(genespool));  
    if (genespool(ind)%stackdepth <= stackdepth) then
          done = .True.
    end if         
  end do

  ! Generate output
  print*, "genespool(ind)  ", genespool(ind);    
  print*, "gene 2          ", gene2;
 gene2=genespool(ind)
  print*, "new gene 2      ",gene2;
  print*, "new gene2.gene     ",gene2%gene;
  answer2=gene2%gene;

  print*, "test 2 ", answer;
  if ( gene2(1)%gene == '#' ) then
    call random_number(rnd1);
  !  gene2%gene = nint(rnd1*5);   !<------ problem (convert integer to string integer)
  endif  
  return;      
  end function newgene 
end function newchromosome

program testing1
! ------ unit declaration ----------------------------------------------
use iso_fortran_env
implicit none
! ----------------------------------------------------------------------
! ------ variable declaration ------------------------------------------
integer                 :: chromlen;
integer                 :: newchromosome;
integer                 :: test;

  chromlen = 35; 
  test = 0;
  test=int(newChromosome(chromlen));
  print*, "newChromosome is ", test;
 flush( output_unit )

 end program testing1
```

I added some dummy variables such as 'answer2' just for debugging purpose. I marked with arrow where my code in FORTRAN is causing trouble due to Matlab dynamic type declaration.  In FORTRAN, it could be impossible to have a variable that is both character and double (real). In FORTRAN, I cannot have U- and -11 like in Matlab because in FORTRAN has declaration of gene2 type as a character.  Matlab is flexible, FORTRAN is strict.  In FORTRAN, how do I make the gene2.gene accept 'real type' -11 without causing an error?  Is there a better way making a type declaration such as %ptr or class(*) for heterogeneous array declaration?

Comment: Do you have some Fortran code we can talk about? Fortran is statically typed language, but there is some polymorphism possible (`class(*)`). But it may not be helpful here. A Fortran code is needed to be sure. It may just be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I added fortran code solution.  I marked with arrow at the point where I am stuck due to nature of matlab code line where dynamic variable occurs.   That is, it can be both character and double.

Comment: Note that your syntax is very strange. You don't need those semicolons (`;`). Matlab does not need them and Fortran also does not, it is quite the same as Matlab in this regard.

Comment: So what shall be the ultimate answer or result returned by the functions `newgene` and `newchromosome`? A number or a string? Don't you just need the integer to string conversion? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262695/convert-integers-to-strings-to-create-output-filenames-at-run-time  I do not see the function results to be set anywhere.

Comment: Okay, I did not know the reason for semicolon in fortran.  However matlab does need it  if you dont want to see output of each variable in output window.

Comment: The output of Matlab is that gene = 'x 0 1' and if gene =' # 0 1' (see if condition) then gene = '4 0 1'   Of course, number 4 is generated randomly therefore it could have any number.  This is my problem. Matlab structure is character, integer, integer.  In FORTRAN it will be types character, integer, integer.  However, in Matlab, one can set double, integer, integer. dynamically.  But in FORTRAN, as you said , the types are static.  Is there a work around.  You mentioned class (*) but I've seen it deals with integer, real and complex.   I did not see how it deals with character and real.

Comment: But what is the output supposed to be? A string? I don't believe you need anything like such a dynamic array. Really, I ask again: *"So what shall be the ultimate answer or result returned by the functions newgene and newchromosome? A number or a string?"* Please answer by adding enough details to your question.

Comment: Please do look into the link I provided. Isn't just conversion of a number to a string what you actually want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262695/convert-integers-to-strings-to-create-output-filenames-at-run-time

Comment: Okay, I will update the listing so that it can be tested with Octave (m code) and fortran (f90 code).   Note that I found a similar problem and its solution that seems not to work.  Please see the link.....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621185/creating-heterogeneous-arrays-in-fortran

Comment: I updated the code listing.  The output should be array type like in matlab

Comment: Yes I know the technique you linked very well. It *might* help. Bet there is ni way to apply to your code because you still did not answer my two questions. What should those two functions return? Not just a type. You are not trying to set the return value anywhere. **Which Fortran array should be the heterogeneous one?** Your testing program also does not try to prrint any useful values, just some length of something. Notice I am asking several points, please deal with them one by one.

Comment: Please notice you do not even show the output of the Matlab program so we can't really know what the same output as Matlab means. But if you think your link answers your question we can close your wuestion as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Okay, I will try my best.  Note that I run into fortran method called ' %ptr  ' which I am not familiar with.

Comment: Regarding my link, the compiler rejects this  short code alone which is " TYPE :: wrapper
  CLASS(*), ALLOCATABLE :: item
END TYPE wrapper

CALL sub([wrapper(1), wrapper(2.0), wrapper('3')])" Besides, I do not know how to implement that into my problem code testing1.f90.  I am using gfortran.

Comment: I am getting error message " Error: Can't convert CHARACTER(1) to CLASS(*) at (1) "  I guess CLASS(*) does not work in that case.

Comment: Well, now your error messages do not even correspond to the code in the question. That is not going to work, is it? Please make clear question and put all the info there. Do not use comments for important information. Try to be concise in descriptions but detsiled in code and error messages. You do not have to implement the nee technique yet, let people tell you if there is somethiing simpler possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think I finally understand your code. And, if I do, what you want is to have the component `gene%gene` to be able to display a character or a number, when needed.

You definitely do not need/want to simulate a dynamic type or anything that hard, though. You can just maintain the component as a character type and if you need to store an integer, you convert it to text. In Fortran, conversion of other types into character is done with the same I/O statements you are used to, but you pass a character variable instead of a unit number. Like this:

```
write(gene2%gene, '(i0)') int(rnd1 * 5);
```

This statement will write the integer value of the passed expression into the character component. The format `(i0)` will use the minimum space needed for the number, in this case. If you need to store a real variable instead of an integer, use the same principle; but you may need to increase the length of the character component and use a different format, maybe `(g0)`.

---

Even though this technically solves your question, I wrote a port of your Matlab program in, as I consider, a more "Fortran-ish" way. You may used it as a exercise to learn some language concepts and constructs you may not be familiar.

Wrap functionality into a module:

```fortran
module genetics
  implicit none

  ! use a constant, so it will be easier to refactor when needed
  integer, parameter :: g_charlen = 2

  type gene
    character(g_charlen) :: gene
    integer :: depth
    integer :: delta
  end type

  ! initializing in a data statement looks nicer in this case
  type(gene) :: pool(8)
  data pool%gene  / '#', 'U-', 'Rs',  '+',  '-',  '*',  '/',  '^'/
  data pool%depth /   0,    0,    1,    2,    2,    2,    2,    2/
  data pool%delta /   1,    1,    0,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1/

  ! or whatever implementation you may have
  type chromosome
    character(g_charlen) :: gene
    integer :: stack
  end type

contains

  ! there is no need for nested procedures in this case
  function new_gene(depth) result(out)
    integer, intent(in) :: depth
    type(gene) :: out
    real :: rnd

    associate(filtered => pack(pool, pool%depth <= depth))
      if(size(filtered) < 1) error stop 'there is no suitable gene in the pool'
      call random_number(rnd)
      out = filtered(int(rnd * size(filtered)) + 1)
    end associate
    if(out%gene == '#') then
      call random_number(rnd)
      write(out%gene, '(i0)') int(rnd * 5) ! <- here is the line
    end if
  end

  ! or whatever implementation you may have
  function new_chromosome(clen) result(out)
    integer, intent(in) :: clen
    type(chromosome), allocatable :: out(:)
    type(gene) :: g
    integer :: i, depth
    real :: rnd
    character(g_charlen) :: gch

    allocate(out(0))
    depth = 0
    i = 1
    do while(i <= clen .or. depth /= 1)
      g = new_gene(depth)
      depth = depth + g%delta
      out = [out, chromosome(g%gene, depth)]
      i = i + 1
      if(g%gene == 'X') then
        call random_number(rnd)
        if(rnd >= 0.5) cycle
        call random_number(rnd)
        write(gch, '(i0)') int(rnd * 3) + 2;
        out = [out, chromosome(gch, depth + 1), chromosome('^', depth - 1)]
      end if
    end do
  end
end
```

And you can test the code with:

```fortran
program test
  use :: genetics
  implicit none

  type(chromosome), allocatable :: c1(:)
  integer :: i

  call random_seed
  c1 = new_chromosome(10)
  do i = 1, size(c1)
    print *, c1(i)
  end do
end
```

One posible output is:

```
 1            1
 U-           2
 *            1
 U-           2
 1            3
 2            4
 -            3
 U-           4
 U-           5
 ^            4
 /            3
 Rs           3
 -            2
 0            3
 -            2
 ^            1
```