# Is there a standard Fortran command to write something to terminal and to a file simultaneously?

Tags: fortran, output

I mean a single command equivalent to

```
write(*,*) something
write(file,*) something
```

Or should I just write my own subroutine?

Comment: Yes, write your own subroutine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print and write in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30091152/print-and-write-in-one-line)